# Eclipse editor specifically doesn't load POM.XML (Linux/Raspbian)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using the newest version of Raspbian (NOOBS install) on my Raspberry Pi 3. I have tried time and time again to uninstall Eclipse & redownload, but to no avail. I can load the editor just fine when it's a .class file, but when loading pom.XML (since I much prefer Maven as a build-tool), I get this stacktrace;

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/sse/core/internal/provisional/IStructuredModel
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(EditorManager.java:875)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2946)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2846)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2797)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2777)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenPomWizard$2.run(MavenPomWizard.java:151)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:388)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenPomWizard.performFinish(MavenPomWizard.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions.EnableNatureAction.enableNature(EnableNatureAction.java:115)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.actions.EnableNatureAction.run(EnableNatureAction.java:94)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3562)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core (296).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentType.getDescriber(ContentType.java:271)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.collectMatchingByContents(ContentTypeCatalog.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:403)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:450)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:346)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:360)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeMatcher.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeMatcher.java:86)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.readDescription(ContentDescriptionManager.java:445)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.getDescriptionFor(ContentDescriptionManager.java:355)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContentDescription(File.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.getContentType(IDE.java:1517)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.getDefaultEditor(IDE.java:1448)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.getEditorDescriptor(IDE.java:833)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:653)
... 51 more
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
... 82 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.utils.StringUtils.unpack(StringUtils.java:734)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.projectHasNotBeenFullyScanned(TaskScanningJob.java:129)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningJob.addProject(TaskScanningJob.java:95)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.enqueue(TaskScanningScheduler.java:138)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.tasks.TaskScanningScheduler.startup(TaskScanningScheduler.java:118)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.SSECorePlugin.start(SSECorePlugin.java:90)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
... 88 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 97 more
```

If it helps, I installed Eclipse using apt-get in my Terminal window, meaning it is version 3.8. I've tried running with --clean / -clean but that didn't help

(Also, it probably doesn't do wonders that I'm also new to Linux / Raspberry Pi.)

Comment: Eclipse 3.8 is very old, Eclipse Photon (4.8) is the current release.

Comment: @greg-449 Yep, I know - I just don't think it would run very well on RPi, which is why I'm using apt-get (which gives me 3.8).

Comment: Do you have the eclipse-wtp-xmltools package installed? The XML Editor is a different editor from a different plug-in than the Java tools.

Comment: Could be a [jvm conflict with Eclipse](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3416019), make sure you are running a [compatible JVM version](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_3.8.html#TargetOperatingEnvironments).

Comment: @nitind I ended up installing it & it did briefly change the error to a NullPointerException, but after coming back a few hours later it is right back where it was with the error

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I don't know if it conflicts with what I have going on, but I'm currently running Oracle's Java 7 JDK (apt-get), is there something else I would need to install if that were the case?

Comment: So it's back to the exact same exception trace even with the package installed?

Comment: @nitind Nope - just had a closer look at it. Exception type is still the same, but a few things are switched
I made a pastebin for the new exception: https://pastebin.com/N9HCYdMv

Comment: How are you installing (and uninstalling) all of this? These dependencies should be in other packages and automatically handled if the packagers tested any of this.

Comment: @nitind I use `apt-get install eclipse` to install & then when uninstalling I use `apt-get autoremove eclipse*` and `apt-get purge eclipse` , then I check to see if any folders are still lingering, and if they are, I delete them